# Lync 2013 Profile picture extension

Tags: image, sdk, profile, wireshark, lync-2013

Our company recently switched to Lync 2013 and I noticed that under "Settings/My Profile Picture" there is no longer an option to specify a profile image. In Lync 2013 you could at least set a picture with less than 30kb that is hosted on a webserver.
The funny thing is I can use my Lync 2013 server account with the old Lync 2010 client and then I'm still able to set a profile picture (tested & woks).
Seems as Microsoft just killed this feature in the client but not on the server (LOL!?!?).

I would like to write a tool to be able to set a picture without having to install the old Lync 2010 client. Any hints, solutions or something to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update as of 12/11/2013

The latest Lync update (**Lync Client CU3 (November Update)**) has the option to set a photo added back to the GUI.

- [Link to the KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825630/en-us)
- [Link to the Download](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825630/en-us)

Article with explanations and screenshots can be found here: [Lync Client CU3 (November Update) – Show a picture from a website!](http://masteringlync.com/2013/11/11/lync-client-cu3-november-update-show-a-picture-from-a-website/).

---

### Original Answer

This question comes up more often. It's indeed just a user interface change between the Lync 2010 and 2013 clients, the option to set an image URL has been removed. Underwater this option is still available though, and you can publish a Photo URL to the server from a user endpoint, or from a powershell admin screen as posted in [GodEater's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093821/928483).

I answered with a description on how to publish photos using a user endpoint (wheter from client SDK or UCMA) here: [Display User Picture in Lync 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404440/display-user-picture-in-lync-2013/19546129#19546129)

Answer (score 1):

Someone's implemented this as a powershell script here (and I've tested that it works on our Lync 2013 infrastructure) :

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Add-Personal-URL-Photo-in-df0136ea